# RxSwift lost order after zip

Tags: swift, rx-swift

Lets say i have an Observable, and an Observable, (names and ages for example), i zip them and i do some transformations with them, but those transformation inside the zip sometimes i have to go to the network (delay in this example) and others just return a value. So the original order of the tuple(String, Int) gets messy.

```
var shouldDelay = true
func names() -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.of("First name", "John", "Martina")
}
func ages() -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.of(20,15,17)
}
Observable.zip(names(), ages())
    .flatMap{ arg -> Observable<(String, Int)> in
        if shouldDelay {
            shouldDelay = !shouldDelay
            return Observable.just(arg).delay(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        }
        return Observable.just(arg)
    }
    .map { $0.0 + " " + $0.1.description }
.subscribe { event in
    print(event.element ?? "")
}
```

So basically I get `John 15, Martina 17, FirstName 20` (those tuples are correct), but i expect `FirstName 20, John 15, Martina 17`.

Any hints to solve this? I only can think of regrouping them (.toArray) and ordering them inside and finally Observable.from

Comment: this happens only if `shouldDelay` is true?

Comment: Yes, for example consider the delay as a network request to update the age since its outdated to say something (i just simulating it with a delay)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `concatMap` operator instead of `flatMap`?

```
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
var shouldDelay = true
func names() -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.of("First name", "John", "Martina")
}
func ages() -> Observable<Int> {
    return Observable.of(20,15,17)
}
Observable
    .zip(names(), ages())
    .concatMap({ arg -> Observable<(String, Int)> in
        if shouldDelay {
            shouldDelay = !shouldDelay
            return Observable.just(arg).delay(1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
        }
        return Observable.just(arg)
    })
    .map({ $0.0 + " " + $0.1.description })
    .subscribe(onNext: { string in
        print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, string)
    })
```

Output:

> 1515304227.56596
>
> 1515304228.5776 First name 20
>
> 1515304228.58187 John 15
>
> 1515304228.58236 Martina 17

Comment: This is awesome. I finally found another solution which is by far worse than this. After zip enumerating the tuple, and then at the end sorting it. Thanks a lot!